# Cordova app timeout when connecting to local server using ajax

Tags: android, jquery, ajax, jsonp, cordova

I've searched high and low to try and solve this problem but to no avail. I am trying to connect a Phonegap app to the server hosted locally on my machine, but it always times out. I used [this code](http://samcroft.co.uk/2011/updated-loading-data-in-phonegap-using-jquery-1-5/) to assist me in creating a simple app and eventually copied Sam Croft's code completely. It still times out. If I connect to the PHP script on samcroft, the app works and I can retrieve data into my app, but if I replace his URL with mine it times out.  My PHP script runs perfectly in my browser, but not in my Android virtual device. It makes no difference whether I add `http://127.0.0.1*` to my whitelist or not. Oddly(?) even if I do not add `http://samcroft.co.uk*` to my whitelist the app runs properly and retrieves the data when I run the script on samcroft.co.uk. I am developing in Eclipse and using Cordova 2.6.0. and jquery 1.9.1. I have tried older version of these files with the same result.

With the URL in the js code below it works perfectly, but when I replace the URL with `'http://127.0.0.1/landmarks.php'` I get the timeout error. I've tried adding the port number into the URL but get the same error. I've also tried using `'http://localhost/landmarks.php'` with the same error. (The 2 landmark.php files are identical, except mine connects to a local MySQL server).

The js code:

```
    $.ajax({
    url: 'http://samcroft.co.uk/demos/updated-load-data-into-phonegap/landmarks.php',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    jsonp: 'jsoncallback',
    timeout: 5000,
    success: function(data, status){
    $.each(data, function(i,item){
    var landmark = '<h1>'+item.name+'</h1>'
    + '<p>'+item.latitude+'<br>'
    + item.longitude+'</p>';

    output.append(landmark);
    });
    },
    error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
    alert(ajaxOptions);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you are testing with an emulator. If this is the case, `localhost` and `127.0.0.1` will not work because that address refers to the local machine, in this case, the actual emulator itself. Instead you should use `10.0.2.2`, which acts like a "bridge" to your development machine/server hosting the script. You can read more about it [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#networkaddresses):   This would explain why the external samecroft site works.

Comment: Awesome, I'm glad that it worked. It took me a few days to discover that myself, it's one of those things that's easy to miss. Feel free to accept this answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can't just access localhost from your Android device.

Make sure following things are inplace

- Your machine and phone (via wifi) connected to same LAN
- Get your machine's IP and use it instead of  `localhost`
- If you can't still access localhost disable firewall or any anti-virus program running on your machine and try again

This is how I accessed my localhost via mobile phone.

Both phone and emulator can access an external url as they are in the external domain. But to access the localhost you need to be in the same LAN or any other variant (VPN etc.).

Answer (score 0):

You should never use localhost when developing apps, use the local IP for the server instead. Localhost is the machine who make the call to the server. 
When you try on a real device, localhost is the device, and the device doesn't have a server installed, so it will fail. 
BTW, to test on a real device, it has to be connected to the same network.